# Werkzeug version view/change on debian/ubuntu odoo 9

Tags: ubuntu, debian, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

How view current version of werkzeug on debian / ubuntu and install other version from downloads directory?

Any example with terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view all installed python module version you can use `pip freeze`

For Werkzeug

[image]

You should use virtualenv, and with it you can install your desired version of any python module

Comment: Note: for install pip:  sudo apt-get install python-setuptools  and sudo easy_install pip  after complete pip freeze work fine